# Ransack query on multiple fields with curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

Using the [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) Rubygem, I am trying to make a query against two conditions using a curl. This for searching ability being added to an API.

**Query on a single field**

```
curl -X GET -G 'http://localhost:3000/api/v2/products' -d 'q[barcode_eq]=7610200237576'
```

This works

```
Processing by Api::V2::ProductsController#index as */*
  Parameters: {"q"=>{"barcode_eq"=>"761063205021"}}
  Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE     "products"."barcode" = '761063205021' LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

**Query on two fields**

```
 curl -X GET -G 'http://localhost:3000/api/v2/products' -d 'q[barcode_eq]=7610200237576' -d 'q[barcode_eq]=7616800205113'
```

Ignores the first query

```
 Started GET "/api/v2/products?q[barcode_eq]=7610200237576&q[barcode_eq]=7616800205113" for ::1 at 2017-01-10 15:34:28 +0100
  Processing by Api::V2::ProductsController#index as */*
  Parameters: {"q"=>{"barcode_eq"=>"7616800205113"}}
  Product Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."barcode" = '7616800205113' LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

What is the correct sentence to search (and / or) against multiple fields using curl or via ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [`*_in`](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack#search-matchers) matcher:

```
 curl -X GET -G 'http://localhost:3000/api/v2/products' -d 'q[barcode_in][]=7610200237576' -d 'q[barcode_in][]=7616800205113'
```

Note the `_in` instead of the `_eq` and the empty brackets (`[]`)